# Como saber si di click sobre una linea en c#

Tags: c#

Buen dia.
Tengo un pequeño problema, estoy haciendo un editor de grafos simple, dibujo 2 `ellipses` y una linea que va al centro de cada uno de esos `ellipses`, necesito que al hacer click sobre la linea esta cambie de color pero no tengo ni idea de como saber cuando se ha dado click sobre cualquier parte de esta linea, agradecería mucho su ayuda :)

```
Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
Nodo n = new Nodo(new Point(100, 100));
Nodo n1 = new Nodo(new Point(200, 200));
Arista a = new Arista(n, n1);//los parametros son nodo origen y nodo destino

g.DrawEllipse(pen, n.centro.X-25, n.centro.Y-25, 50, 50);
g.DrawEllipse(pen, n1.centro.X - 25, n.centro.Y - 25, 50, 50);
g.DrawLine(pen, n.centro, n1.centro);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! como dibujas la linea?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi gracias por el dato, ya estoy leyendo el docmuento, la dibujo con un g.DrawLine(pen,100,100,200,200);

Comment: esa clase de linea no es un objeto y no es clickeable.. es un dibujo.. la proxima vez, usa el boton [edit] y pone el codigo en la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien dice @gbianchi en un comentario, los objetos que se dibujan mediante `Graphics` no son "clickables", así que no tienen un evento `Click`al que suscribirse.

Voy a darte una solución usando las matemáticas. Lo primero que debemos saber es que la ecuación de una recta se define con esta fórmula:

> y = mx + b

Sabiendo esto, lo que debes hacer es almacenar en alguna variable los dos puntos que definen tu recta. Para simplificar todo, voy a trabajar con enteros únicamente.

Siguiendo tu ejemplo, veo que dibujas tu línea de `n.centro` a `n1.centro`, así que estos son los puntos que definen tu línea.

Ahora, lo que hacemos es suscribirnos al evento Click de donde estés dibujando (`Form`, `PictureBox`..). En este ejemplo, al del formulario. En dicho evento, primero calculamos la ecuación de la recta dados dos puntos, y luego comprobamos si el punto donde se ha pulsado corresponde a la recta definida:

```
private void form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point p1 = n.centro;
    Point p2=n1.centro;

    int sensibilidad = 5;

    //Calculamos la ecuación de la recta dados dos puntos
    int m = (p2.Y - p1.Y) / (p2.X - p1.X);
    var b = p1.Y - (m * p1.X);

    //Comprobamos el valor de y en la recta para el valor X del punto pulsado
    int y = m * e.Location.X + b;

    //Si la y está dentro de la línea (con un margen de sensibilidad que decidamos)
    if (e.Location.Y>=y-sensibilidad && e.Location.Y<=y+sensibilidad)
    {
        //estás en la linea
        MessageBox.Show("Estás en la línea");
    }
}
```

Como la línea es un objeto muy fino, definimos una "sensibilidad" para que sea mas fácil detectar el click.